# Why my for loop doesn't change the original dataframe in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I tried to feed a for loop my dataframe so the loop can make a new column one row at a time with the number from another reference dataframe. Below is my code so far

```
for (Index in 1:nrow(pH6.17)) {
  Row = pH6.17[Index, ]

  RowRef = Row$Ref
  # print(RowRef)
  
  RowRefNum = pH6.17Reference$Avg[match(RowRef,pH6.17Reference$Ref)] #Find the index of RowRef in the column pH6.17Reference$Ref and then use that index to locate the corresponding Avg in the column pH6.17Reference
  # print(RowRefNum)
  
  RowCellViability = Row$Avg/RowRefNum #Calculate the CellViability 
  # print(RowCellViability)
  
  Row$CellViability <- RowCellViability #Assign it back to the Row in a new column  
  # print(Row)
}

pH6.17
```

The dataframes pH6.17 before and after the for loop are exactly the same. I came from Python so this is very weird to me. After some research, I understand that for loop in R works on a copy of the input dataframe. Also I assume there'll be easier ways to do the work with some functions. But I just want to stick with the for loop and could someone tell me where I got wrong in the syntax of my for loop please? I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data frame won't change unless you assign something **to it**.

`Row` is a copy of the `Index` row that you extracted from the data frame - they are not linked.

You need, inside your loop, to have `pH6.17` on the left hand side of an assignment. I'm not sure of your goal exactly, but try adding this as the last line of your loop:

```
pH6.17[Index, ] <- Row
```

Or, if you are trying to create a new column that doesn't exist in the data frame, I would suggest this:

```
pH6.17$CellViability = NA ## initialize column with missing values
for (Index in 1:nrow(pH6.17)) {
  Row = pH6.17[Index, ]

  RowRef = Row$Ref
  # print(RowRef)
  
  RowRefNum = pH6.17Reference$Avg[match(RowRef,pH6.17Reference$Ref)] #Find the index of RowRef in the column pH6.17Reference$Ref and then use that index to locate the corresponding Avg in the column pH6.17Reference
  # print(RowRefNum)
  
  RowCellViability = Row$Avg/RowRefNum #Calculate the CellViability 
  # print(RowCellViability)
  
  # Assign the value to the data frame
  pH6.17$CellViability[Index] = RowCellViability 
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me why for the very last part, I cannot use "Row$CellViability = RowCellViability"?

Comment: `Row$CellViability = RowCellViability` modifies this `Row` object you've created. It doesn't do anything to `pH6.17`. You want the changes to happen in `pH6.17`, so you need to explicitly modify the `pH6.17` data frame.